# Calculate $\int\limits_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot F \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$During some new lecture series I started to attend I was given the following exercise. It involves vector calculus with which I am rather weak. Therefore, it might be elementary and trivial to some people here.

The **exercise** goes as below:

> Let $h \in C^{1}([0, \infty))$ with $h(0) = 0$ and $$h'(t) > 0. \quad \forall t \in [0,\infty).$$Furthermore, let $$\Psi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}, \quad \Psi(x_1, x_2, x_3) = h(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)$$ and $\Omega := \Psi^{-1}([0,T])$, $T > 0$.
>
> Let $$F: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, \quad F(x_1, x_2, x_3) = g(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)(x_1, x_2, x_3)^{\text{T}},$$ where $g\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$.  Now calculate $$\int_{\Omega} \nabla\cdot F\,\d x.$$

My **thoughts** are as follows.

First of all, I am new to the notation $\nabla \cdot F$. I suppose that "$\cdot$"  is the dot product and $$\nabla \cdot F = \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x_3},$$ that is, divergence. I just know it as $\text{div}\,F$. If this is the case, I suppose it involves the Gaussian divergence theorem which says $$ \int_{\Omega} \mathrm{div}\, F\,\d\Omega = \int_{\partial \Omega} F\cdot n \,\d(\partial\Omega).$$ The points where I am more or less stuck now are

1. How do I find the boundary $\partial \Omega$?
2. How do I find the normal vector $n$ on this boundary?

With regard to the second question, I know that I can find a (unitary) normal by considering the gradient of some function but I don't know which function to consider.

Comment: The edit of the almost one year old question was really not necessary, Alex Francisco. You did not change anything substantial and the answer was already given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, I got my hands on the **solution**. It goes as follows.

The conditions $h(0) = 0$ and $h'(t) > 0$ imply that there is either one point $t_0 \in [0, \infty]$ for which it holds that $h(t_0) = T$ or none. Let $A$ denote the first case and $B$ the second.

In general, since $\Psi : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}, \Psi(x) = h(\lvert x\rvert_2^2)$, it is $\Omega := \Psi^{-1}([0, T]) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}\;\vert \;h(\lvert x\rvert^2) \leq T\}$. In case A, there exists exactly one $t_0 \in [0, \infty)$: $h(t_0) = T$, therefore $$\Omega = \{ x\, \vert \, h(\lvert x\rvert^2 \leq h(t_0)\} = \{x \, \vert \, \lvert x \rvert \leq \sqrt{t_0}\} = B_{\sqrt{t_0}}(0)$$

In case B, it is $\Omega =\mathbb{R}^3$ since $h(t) < T \, \forall t \in [0, \infty)$.

So, after we found the appropriate set $\Omega$, we can integrate relatively easy. The usual relation is 
$$\int\limits_{\Omega} \nabla\cdot F\, dx = \int\limits_{\partial \Omega} F \nu \, dS$$ In case A, $\partial \Omega = \partial B_{\sqrt{t_0}}(0)$ and $\nu = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t_0}} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$. It then follows that

$$ \int\limits_{\partial \Omega} F \nu ds = \int\limits_{\partial \Omega} g(\lvert x\rvert^2)\frac{1}{R}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} dS = g(R^2)\cdot R\int\limits_{\partial \Omega} ds = 4\pi R^3 g(R^2)$$

Funnily, in case B you cannot apply the Gaussian theorem since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not compact. I guess the one who posed the exercise missed that.